# CS8622 Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'sender'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I turned on TreatWarningsAsErrors in my net6.0-windows SDK project and  am trying to solve the error

> Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'sender' of void myhander doesnt match the target delegate (possibly because of nullability attributes)

The code is

```
pricingBinder = new BindingSource() { DataSource = _pricingbo };
if (pricingBinder_DataError != null)
{
    pricingBinder.DataError -= pricingBinder_DataError;
    pricingBinder.DataError += pricingBinder_DataError;
}
```

The event handler is

```
private void pricingBinder_DataError(object sender, BindingManagerDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    throw new MyGeneralException("## pricingBinder_DataError {0} | {1}");
}
```

[image: error message]

I expect it has something to do with checking whether my event handler can be null but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: It's not your event handler being null or not, it's the signature of your method. That's what I understand from the error message anyway.

Comment: Who makes event handlers static ? Hope you got a good reason for that.

Comment: Oops. I corrected it but the error remains.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its because `BindingManagerDataErrorEventHandler` requires nullable sender in definition.
You can read about it here: [BindingManagerDataErrorEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerdataerroreventhandler?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

So you need to change your code from:

```
private void pricingBinder_DataError(object sender, BindingManagerDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    throw new MyGeneralException("## pricingBinder_DataError {0} | {1}");
}
```

to

```
private void pricingBinder_DataError(object? sender, BindingManagerDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    throw new MyGeneralException("## pricingBinder_DataError {0} | {1}");
}
```