# Registering multiple controls to the same method not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with multiple NumericUpDown controls. I want to registered their enter event to the same method in code:

```
private void AdditionalInitialisation()
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if(control is NumericUpDown) 
        {
            control.Enter += NumericUpDown_Enter;
        }
    }
}

private void NumericUpDown_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((NumericUpDown)sender).Select(0, ((NumericUpDown)sender).Text.Length);
    ((NumericUpDown)sender).BackColor = Color.Wheat;
}
```

Initially I was seeing this notice (i.e. an editor squiggly, not a proper warning):

> Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'sender' of void
> myhander doesnt match the target delegate (possibly because of
> nullability attributes)

Based on this [CS8622 Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'sender'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950764/cs8622-nullability-of-reference-types-in-type-of-parameter-sender) I updated the second methods signature (added '?':

```
private void NumericUpDown_Enter(object**?** sender, EventArgs e)
```

But now I get this notice:

> CS8600 - Converting null literal or possible null value to
> non-nullable type.

And regardless, it's not working. The controls are not being registered.

Comment: Both of them are warnings, unless you have turned them to errors, they are not the reason why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to handle the possibility that `sender` is null. I'd rewrite your code like this:

```cs
private void NumericUpDown_Enter(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not NumericUpDown control)
    {
        return;
    }
    control.Select(0, control.Text.Length);
    control.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
}
```

Now that won't fix "the controls are not registered" but we can't really help with that without more context. I would encourage you to use a debugger in the `foreach` loop to look at a) whether it's executing at all; b) whether it's finding any `NumericUpDown` controls to add an event handler to.

Comment: Thanks, that works. There's definitely something odd going on with the event registration, but that's a story for another day kids :)