# How can I make c# form refreash automaticlly?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi im new at c# and im trying to make like a messagebord.

The goal here is that a person can write in a rtf document and save it and it should be visible on another computer in my program. The problem is that I can't get my program to refresh so that the new text is displayed.

I have tryed this that i found here but it wont work.
It gives me an error [**cs8622**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#mismatch-in-nullability-declaration)

> Nullability of reference types in type of parameter doesn't match the target delegate (possibly because of nullability attributes).

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace messageboard
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            board.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\steve\Desktop\test.rtf");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = (10 * 1000); // 10 secs
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //refresh here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the loadfile in the Timer_Tick?? You'll have to save the file "on the other side" though (probably on a similar interval). And make sure the file is in a location where both computers can access it. `cs8622` is a nullability warning and likely has nothing to do with it.

Comment: File I/O in a CTOR is not the best of ideas anyway, in general - not just here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS8622 Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'sender'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950764/cs8622-nullability-of-reference-types-in-type-of-parameter-sender)

Comment: `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);` => Try `timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;`

Comment: Completely unrelated: Have you thought about how to handle concurrent changes? (Clients A and B have Version 1 of that rtf. A adds something to it while B adds something different to it. When A saves it and then B, A's changes will be gone...)

Comment: @Fildor did no difference

Comment: Can you mark the exact line that this warning/erro points to?

Comment: @Fildor i fixed the error by changing `private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` to `private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)`  so now I dont have any errors but it still wont work

Comment: OK, great. Progress! haha. Now: update the code in the question and add what the new error looks like. Or if you don't see an error, what happens that you don't expect resp. what does not happen that you do expect.

Comment: Note that you probably need to keep file locking in mind, i.e. the writer locks the file during writing, and the reader needs some way to handle locked files. Trying to read a file while it is being updated may cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798197/use-filesystemwatcher-on-a-single-file-in-c-sharp - related?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make your 'board' to a RichTextBox and every single time the board should be refreshed, you simply reload the entire rtf document.

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     board.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\steve\Desktop\test.rtf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements is to just refresh your board.
Rather than timer, which will refresh after every interval, it would be better to use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-8.0) class in .Net, whenever your file is changed, you will get a notification,

Here is the sample code for it.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();  
watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\steve\Desktop\test.rtf";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

// Add event handlers.  
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);


public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)  
{  
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed.  
    board.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\steve\Desktop\test.rtf");
}
```